# Проблема со сбором данных

Tags: оптимизация, обработка, данные

Всем привет, кто-нибудь знает приложение для гибкого сбора данных от сотрудников внутри компании, в котором не нужен программист для создания таблиц в БД или интерфейса, чтобы любой сотрудник мог сам задать, например, какие поля ему нужны, какие ограничения на них и т.п., а на основе этого появится какой то интерфейс? А то постоянно либо от всех эксели собираешь по почте, которые никто правильно заполнить не может, либо приходится привлекать программистов.

P.S. ввод ограничений в эксель не помогает, зачастую все просто удаляют твой файл и кидают новый или их отключают, в интернете ничего похожего не удалось найти.

Comment: [google forms](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ru&oco=0) подойдет? если уже есть office 365 то [microsoft forms](https://www.office.com/launch/forms?auth=1)

Comment: "ввод ограничений в эксель не помогает" для таких случаев в компаниях принято использовать административный ресурс, прислали не тот файл - считай ничего не прислали, выговор -> штраф -> увольнение =) Поможет решить попутно кучу проблем